# Error Java Exception java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java I am getting this Exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

and here is the code:

```
class Worker extends Thread
{
   public void run() {
   System.out.println("#");
 }
}

class Seconda extends Thread
{
   public void run() {
       System.out.println("*");
   }
}


public class First
{
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int contatore=0;
      Worker prova = new Worker();
      Seconda prova2 = new Seconda();
      prova.start();
      prova2.start();
      for(;;) {
               if(!prova.isAlive()) { prova.start();
                                      contatore++;
                                    } 
           if(!prova2.isAlive()) { prova2.start();
                                   contatore++;
                                 }
           if(contatore==50) System.out.println(""); 
          }

   }
 }
```

What does the exception mean?

Comment: Once a thread is terminated you cannot restart it! You have to create a new `Thread` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to start a thread which has already been started.

What you need to do is create the prova and prova2 inside the for loop?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int contatore=0;
  //Worker prova = new Worker();
  //Seconda prova2 = new Seconda();
  //prova.start();
  //prova2.start();
  for(;;) {
     Worker prova = new Worker();
     Seconda prova2 = new Seconda();
     if(!prova.isAlive()) { 
        prova.start();
        contatore++;
     } 
     if(!prova2.isAlive()) { 
        prova2.start();
        contatore++;
     }
     if(contatore==50) System.out.println(""); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a thread more than one times. If you start a thread more than onceyou will get a `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Try,

```
new Thread(prova).start();
new Thread(prova).start();
```

if you need to start the same thread.

For [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663426/why-cant-we-call-start-method-twice-on-a-same-instance-of-the-thread-object)

Answer (score 0):

You must not start a thread multiple times. It can only be started once. See the JavaDoc of [Thread.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once.
>
> [..]
>
> Throws IllegalThreadStateException if the thread was already started.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;;) {
               if(!prova.isAlive()) { prova.start();  // trying to start a started thread again
                                      contatore++;
                                    } 
           if(!prova2.isAlive()) { prova2.start();// trying to start a started thread 
                                   contatore++;
                                 }
           if(contatore==50) System.out.println(""); 
          }

   }
```

You should read about the life cycle of threads. If you try to start an already started thread (it can be alive or otherwise) you will get a IllegalThreadStateException. Please read thread documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can't just start a `Thread` more than one time, you should create a new instance of that `Thread` in order to do the task again.

So you should do something like this:

```
if(!prova.isAlive()) {
    Worker p = new Worker();
    p.start();
    contatore++;
}
```

Java doc:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Read more about Java [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)